# dart / flutter how to make http post request with empty body

Tags: flutter, dart, http

I am trying to call post url but the body payload needs to be empty. While requesting the api from postman, it is working fine. However, when calling from dart http.post it is not working.

Here is my code

```
final response = await http.post(Uri.parse("$baseUrl/api/logout"),
headers: {
  "Accept": "*/*",
},
);
```

which results in 400 response code

and this is my raw http request

```
POST /api/logout HTTP/1.1
Host: <url>
Accept: */*
```

which results in 200 response code.

Answer (score 0):

Use insted to do that.

Try keeping json body null the

```
headers: {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Content-Length" : 0
  }
```

Comment: api is post api cannot use get

Comment: This is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make an `HTTP Request` without a body. You need to use `HEAD` method.

```
  Future httHead() async {
   var baseUrl = Uri.parse("https://stackoverflow.com/");
   final response = await http.head(baseUrl,
   headers: {
     "Accept": "*/*",
   },

  );
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, not working with HEAD

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
var request = {"": ""};

_formRepository.mailWillToOwner(id, request, (response, error) async {
  if (response != null) {
    if (response.success == true) {
      showMessage(response.message, isToast: true);
    } else {
      showMessage(response.message, isToast: true);
    }
  } else {
    showMessage(error);
  }
});
```

if your request body is map or map<dynamic,string>,it will work too